# How do I enter multiple payments for one pledge?

Tags: civicontribute, pledges

I've entered a pledge.  The donor has only paid part of their first payment and plans to make a payment for the balance in a month.  However, the pledge bumped the overdue amount to the following year's pledge.  And it appears that I cannot enter a payment against the first year's pledge now.

Answer (score 2):

Click to expand the pledge payment schedule and then click edit on the expected installment set up for next year - you can change the date back to the current year.

Unless you are dealing with multi-year pledges, consider creating them with a single installment to occur every one day - in this way, the system will transfer the remaining balance as being due the following day as opposed to the following year.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark the answer as accepted so that the question can be closed. Kind regards, Tamar

Comment: Hi Tamar -- I attempted to mark the answer as accepted, but it timed out.  I'll try later.